# Array appending not working across files in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Im currently implementing a like functionality in my app, and I can't seem to be able to get this append and retrieving to work. Here is my Button Action **which is found in my ViewController file**

```
var Liked = Favourite()
let factBook = FactBook()

 @IBAction func favour() {
        var currentQuote = factBook.factsArray[factIndex]
        Liked.favouriteArray.append(currentQuote)

    }
```

The Favourite struct is called from

```
 import Foundation

    struct Favourite {

    var favouriteArray: [String] = []


     }
```

(The factBook struct is the same thing except the array actually has elements inside.)

Now my goal is to get all this to display on a separate view controller called favouriteViewController:

```
  import UIKit

class FavouriteViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var LikeQuote: UILabel!
      var liked = Favourite()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if liked.favouriteArray.count > 0 {
LikeQuote.text = liked.favouriteArray[0]

        } else if liked.favouriteArray.count == 0 {

            LikeQuote.text = "No Liked Quotes Found, Go Favour Some!"
        }
   }
```

Now when I hit the button, **theoretically I should be able to append it to the favouriteArray** and then be able to display it on my favouriteViewController file, however when I save it and then open viewcontroller file **it defaults to the liked.favouriteArray.count=0** scenario and prints out the text no matter how many quotes I save. I just need an idea of what's going wrong in this process?

Update: If I put append Hello world into text it still does not append to element and evaluates the array value as 0.

Comment: You are not saving those data no where so you won't be able to retrieve them

Comment: Remove that local redeclaration of var liked = Favourite within viewDidload.   You have the global var  already.

Comment: @nshebbar generating error: use of unresolved identifier if I do that.

Comment: i just reformat your code so why do you have two Liked Object

Comment: @Lamar can't see it.

Comment: @Lamar Yes, I took the suggestion of the liked object but the button inside favourite is not really needed

Comment: @Lamar doesn't solve the issue at hand though

Comment: Why don't you pass it to the FavouriteViewController from ViewController?  How are you instatiating this FavouriteViewController?

Comment: @Lamar pretty much same format as favourite but just many quote collection elements.

Comment: @nshebbar I don't understand...?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that because you are not saving the data somewhere like into a database or file, you won't be able to retrieve it so the code you add into the **viewDidLoad will not work** The only way for it to work is when the UIButton was tapped check the code below. Hope that Helps

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


struct Favourite {
    var favouriteArray = [String]()
}



class FavouriteViewController: UIViewController {

   // let factBook = FactBook()

    @IBOutlet var LikeQuote: UILabel!

    var liked = Favourite()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func updateContent(){
        if liked.favouriteArray.count > 0 {
            LikeQuote.text = liked.favouriteArray[0]
        }
        else if liked.favouriteArray.count == 0 {
            LikeQuote.text = "No Liked Quotes Found, Go Favour Some!"
        }


    }

    @IBAction func favour() {
//        var currentQuote = liked.factsArray[factIndex]
//        Liked.favouriteArray.append(currentQuote)

         liked.favouriteArray.append("today is a new day ")
          updateContent()

    }
}
```

Comment: I pretty sure appending some data and displaying it is very possible in swift.

Comment: i did append data check the favour()

Comment: need to append a specific quote at a certain index, not just today is a new day.

Comment: you can visualize the factbook array as [1,2,3] and what difference would it make?